# Centering Bootstrap Icons Horizontally

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, icons

I'm having trouble centering Bootstrap Icons inside my buttons. As you can see, the icon isn't centered horizontally. I can't get it to work (I've tried text-align, flexbox with justify-content, ...), because apparently the "letter" itself is taking up some extra space on the right - at least that's what it looks like to me. Can anybody help me?

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

button {
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.6.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button>
        <i class="bi-play"></i>
    </button>
</body>
```

Comment: Because different icons and characters have different sizes I don't think it would be possible to center and have it right each time; instead you can add `padding` to the left or right to correct the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with text as what you are trying to center is the i element. Therefore it's the button that needs to be displayed as flex and to set the centering.

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.6.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button>
        <i class="bi-play"></i>
    </button>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, but just look at the button. The Play Icon is slightly to the left. Like I said in my question, I already tried flex-box, even if I didn't include it in the example code.

Comment: Hi, I’ve measured, blown the image up and measured again, removed the curves from the button border and measured again, given the icon a background color and measured again and just cannot find that the icon is to the left. What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: windows and opera gx currently. I looked at the thing again, and measured as well, and it seems to be in the middle. However, I cannot for the life of me begin to see that. For me it looks like its ever so slightly to the left, and there's a bit more space on the right side. I also used different icons, and if they're symmetrical (eg. plus sign) I don't have the problem. So I guess that's actually just me and not the browser...

Comment: I think it may be a sort of optical illusion - because that particular icon is fat on the left hand side and getting on towards non-existent on the right hand side - I had to physically measure to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: red;
}
.bi-play{
color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.6.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button>
        <i class="bi-play my4"></i>
    </button>
</body>
```

Check now if it solves your problem. I think it is centered now.

Comment: You can also use padding inside the button in CSS to move the icon across the main axis and leave it where you think it is centered.